# Implement a dictionary of classes for a pseudo class factory

Tags: c#, factory

I´m trying to buld a class factory like that:

```
public class Toyota() {};
public class Bmw() {};
public class Mercedes() {};

public class BrandFactory
{
    private Dictionary<string, object> _Brands = new Dictionary<string, object> {
        {"Toyota", Toyota},
        {"Bmw", Bmw}, 
        {"Mercedes", Mercedes}
    }

   public object GetBrand(string brandName)
   {
       return = BusinessManagers[brandName].Invoke;
   }
}
```

This is the idea, but it´s not working - I can´t even compile the above code as the Dictionary cannot associate an `'object'` with the function. I tried `Func<>` as well, but in that case it requires a previous type.

So, here are my questions:
Is that a correct way to implement this 'pseudo factory' ? The code came from the example at [example code](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/383845/Factory-Method-Pattern-With-Expression-Trees-using)

If so, what needs to be fixed in the above code ?

The reason I´m asking that is because I need to create a new object based on a string that is received from a cliente application using Ajax. Like:

`AjaxCall -> String Containing Object Name -> Object Inoke -> Method Call -> Send result back to client`

The Method Call is a standard for all implementation of `Brand`.

Please can someone help me with that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need a Dictionary at all:

```
public class DynamicFactory<T>  
{
    public static T Create(string className)
    {
        Type t = typeof(T);
        return (T)Activator.CreateInstance(
                    t.Assembly.FullName, 
                    t.Namespace + "." + className
                  ).Unwrap();
    }
}
namespace Brands
{
    public class CarBrand { }

    // The brands should be in the same namespace and assembly with CarBrand
    // and should inherit from CarBrand
    public class Toyota : CarBrand { };
    public class Bmw : CarBrand { };
    public class Mercedes : CarBrand { };

    public class Titanic { } // this one is not CarBrand

    class BrandFactory: DynamicFactory<CarBrand> { }

    // Below are unit tests using NUnit

    namespace BrandFactorySpecification 
    {
        static class Create
        {
            [TestCase("Toyota", Result = typeof(Toyota))]
            [TestCase("Bmw", Result = typeof(Bmw))]
            [TestCase("Mercedes", Result = typeof(Mercedes))]
            [TestCase("Titanic", ExpectedException = typeof(InvalidCastException))]
            [TestCase("unknown", ExpectedException = typeof(TypeLoadException))]
            [TestCase("String", ExpectedException = typeof(TypeLoadException))]
            [TestCase("System.String", ExpectedException = typeof(TypeLoadException))]
            [TestCase("ACarBrandFromAnotherNamespace", 
                          ExpectedException = typeof(TypeLoadException))]
            [TestCase("AnotherNamespace.ACarBrandFromAnotherNamespace",
                          ExpectedException = typeof(TypeLoadException))]
            //
            public static Type ShouldReturnCorrectType(string brandName)
            {
                return BrandFactory.Create(brandName).GetType();
            }

            [Test]
            public static void ForTitanic()
            {
                DynamicFactory<Titanic>.Create("Titanic")
                    .ShouldBeType(typeof(Titanic));
            }
        }

        namespace AnotherNamespace
        {
            public class ACarBrandFromAnotherNamespace : CarBrand { };
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**: the code was improved in the following ways:

- The security problem, mentioned in the comments was fixed
- flexibility improved

  - A new generic `class DynamicFactory<T>` now can be reused elsewhere
  - `Brands` can be located in other namespace and assembly then `BrandFactory`
- Unit tests were added to serve as examples of usage and specification (using [NUnit](http://nunit.org/) required for them)

Comment: It is true that if the class names match the user input, `Activator` could be used in this way. I'd argue that the `Dictionary` approach is superior from a security perspective because the input must be a known value. With this approach an AJAX call from anywhere could cause other, unintended classes to be instantiated. Hardcoding the namespace does help, and it could probably be mitigated further by putting all of the "brand" classes into their own, dedicated namespace.

Comment: This does not work, since the string is `"BMW"` while the class name is `Bmw`. Thanks for your editing of my post BTW :).

Comment: I do have a Brand namespace, where the pseudo factory is. Easier than the dictionary approach. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks AlexD. Corrected BMW to Bmw in my code. Ajax will call it with correct case.

Comment: Another consideration is that the values coming back must be massaged a bit before this will work, as some brands have spaces and characters that cannot be in a class name. `Mercedes-Benz`, `Aston Martin`, `Land Rover`.

Comment: @Jay, I believe the code could be improved to address security by creating a common ancestor class Car and checking the type of the object before returning it

Answer (score 3):

You have a several options here. If you end up using a `Dictionary`, I recommend making it case-insensitive and taking care to avoid `KeyNotFoundException`s.

```
public class CaseInsensitiveStringComparer : IComparer<string>
{
    public int Compare(string x, string y)
    {
        return string.Compare(x, y, ignoreCase: true);
    }
}
```

The first option is to use `Dictionary<string, Func<object>>`.

```
private IDictionary<string, Func<object>> _Brands 
    = new Dictionary<string, Func<object>> (new CaseInsensitiveStringComparer())
{
    {"Toyota", () => new Toyota() },
    {"BMW", () => new Bmw() }, 
    {"Mercedes", () => Mercedes() }
};

public object GetBrand(string brandName)
{
    Func<object> func;
    return _Brands.TryGetValue(brandName, out func)
        ? func() // invoking the delegate creates the instance of the brand object
        : null;  // brandName was not in the dictionary
}
```

Second option is to use `Activator`. You can use a `Dictionary<string,Type>`, but it may not be necessary if your type name matches the string (see notes below).

```
public object GetBrand(string brandName)
{
    Type type;
    return  _Brands.TryGetValue(brandName, out type)
        ? Activator.CreateInstance(type) // activator invokes a parameterless constructor
        : null; // brandName was not in the dictionary
}

// vs.

return Activator.CreateInstance(null, brandName).Unwrap();
// Case sensitivity would be an issue here.
// Security could be an issue here.
// Creating objects based directly off of user input means any class 
// from any referenced assembly could be created if a hacker can learn
// out the namespaces and class names.
```

Third option is to use an IoC container to do the resolution. This gives you some flexibility with lifetime management.

The second approach currently assumes a parameterless constructor, wherease the first and third would allow for disparate constructor signatures.

In all cases, the result is simply `object`, which gives this approach limited utility. If all of these "brand" classes could share a common interface, then you could use `IBrand` or whatever in your `Dictionary` and as the return type.

I'm checking for bad data (values not in the `Dictionary`) and returning `null`; you could choose to throw an `Exception` if that makes more sense for your use case.*

Comment: Yes. I want to get a new object of given type on GetBrand. I have tons of classes, thats why I want to keep that in a dictionary to avoid a long switch statement.

Comment: AS for the downvotes and comments - is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: @Mendez Where is the `string` coming from? Why do you need it?

Comment: string comes from a client application though an Ajax call. The client sends "Bmw" as a string, I need to create the class and call a list method and it and return the result.

Answer (score 1):

That's not at all how a factory works.  First of all you need a superclass that can be the parent of your car models:

```
public class CarModel() {};
public class Toyota() : CarModel {};
public class Bmw() : CarModel  {};
public class Mercedes() : CarModel  {};
```

Now you can create a factory that returns the correct model:

```
public class BrandFactory
{
    public T GetBrand<T>() where T : CarModel
    { 
        return new T(); 
    }
}
```

Now when you want to create a object its is simple:

```
var factory = new BrandFactory();
var bmw = factory.GetBrand<Bmw>();
```

Comment: You need a new constraint on T

Comment: OK, but how can I pass T as string, instead a fixed type ? Inside my logic the Bmw comes to me as a string, not a type.

Comment: …except that the OP wants to create instances from strings.

Comment: your generic version won't work without a new() constraint where T : new()